# JMeter - Response is different between servers (200 instead of OK)

Tags: apache, tomcat, jmeter, http-status-codes, jmeter-5.0

About change in response view of [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> In View Results Tree, the request and response headers/body are clearly separated to allow you to better inspect requests and responses

I see a "valid" response of `200 OK` from one server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
```

and an "invalid" response of `200 200` from other server (same request) :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Server: Apache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Why sometimes it doesn't display the `OK` description of HTTP status code? Is it apache issue or JMeter issue and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

This issue is actually not JMeter related, it appears also in older JMeter version but seen differently in the UI

Comment: maybe because different servers send different headers and JMeter just displays the raw headers? Hmm, reading the tool's documentation could come in handy...

Comment: @jwenting I didn't find it in documentation, both servers have the same code

Comment: they are different servers though, one identifies itself as "Apache-Coyote/1.1" and the other as "Apache". So they ARE different, your code might be the same that's running on them, the rest of the server isn't. And the header is generated not by your code but by the server proper.

Comment: @jwenting are you sure it's apache property? can you provide link/explanation to such property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [HTTP Protocol Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-10.2.1) correct response should look like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, if you're seeing an extra `200` - it indicates the issue with your server and if your application will be used by a tool which checks response message - the request will be considered as failed.

So I would recommend raising an issue as the behaviour is definitely odd.

If your crazy developers are crazy enough to substitute normal response message with duplicate code and you don't want JMeter to fail on these weird responses you can add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) as a child of the "problematic" request and tick `Ignore Status` box